# PHP and SQL wont work?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");

if (!$sql) {
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)); {
        echo $row1;
    }
} else {
    echo "Funker ikke";
}
```

I cant get it to work, all I get is the: else "Funker ikke".

Comment: use `if ($sql) {while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)){echo $row1['0'];} else{echo "Funker ikke";}`

Comment: if($sql) -> is true. You've checked error conditions for true. Please review `Return Values` of `mysqli_query` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: you can try to echo out the  mysql_error, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
also to make sure your query is successful,
you can make use of print_r to check if you have a return data on your query.

Comment: Thank you Saty, but why wouldnt it work with my code, without ['0']?

Comment: @Simen check my answer below `mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)` return numeric array. SO you can;t echo array directly

Answer (score 4):

1) Using wrong if condition. If query return true then insert into if condition

2) Wrong echo data using `MYSQL_NUM`. It return numeric array

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");      

if ($sql) {// if true
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        echo $row1['0'];//numeric array
    }
} else {
    echo "Funker ikke";
}
```

UPDATED as per below comments

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");
if ($sql) {
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM);
    echo $row1['0']; //numeric array
} else {
    echo "Funker ikke";
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You should really be testing `if ($sql !== FALSE) {` as when query is good `$sql` is not `TRUE` it is in fact a `mysqli_result` Object

Comment: @RiggsFolly then that if condition will also return `true` even if its an object

Comment: Also as a `COUNT(ID)` can only return one row, the while loop is unnecessary

Comment: In fact even PHP Manual uses that

Comment: @HankyPanky Yup, thats my point. But is a `mysqli_query()` actually returned `TRUE` there would be something VERY ODD going on! However when it fails in most definitely returns FALSE. I would actually turn the IF around and do a `if ( $sql === FALSE ) {` but I could not fit all that in a comment

Comment: Nope why so? on an successful `INSERT`  it will return `TRUE`. It can return true on a number of cases

Comment: *Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.*

Comment: @HankyPanky TRUE, _But this is NOT an INSERT now is it_ A SELECT returns FALSE or an `mysqli_result` object and `mysqli_result` object is not TRUE, it just looks like a TRUE

Comment: No need for quotes around the index: `$row[0]` will do just fine.

Comment: Gave up trying to fix other peoples answers and gave my own

Comment: @HankyPanky But its all to late Saty is off to the bank with his 30 reps and the answer was probably enough to get the questioner over his issue. So I get no love at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code are having two error there. 
First, it should be true condition only can get into the display loop. But you put the condition as `!$sql` means false only can get into the loop. So, you should change `!$sql` to `$sql`. 
Besides, after the `While` loop should not direct put the semicolon. 
You try see the following code

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");

if ($sql) {
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        echo $row1[0]; 
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Funker ikke";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct except the not sign before sql in if condition.According to you if your sql query is wrong then the $row1 is displayed else if it is correct then "funker ikke" gets printed.Just the opposite.  This code works:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");      

 if ($sql) {
   // as the query can only return 1 row the while look is unnecessary
   //while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)) {

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)
   echo $row[0]; 

 } else {
   echo "Funker ikke";
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked its working with echo $row1; or not? I think its return numeric value. Please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code

First you do not need a while loop to process a single result, SELECT COUNT() can only return one row.

Second as `mysqli_query()` for a SELECT query will return either FALSE or a `mysqli_result` object it would be better to flip your if condition as below and test specifically for FALSE rather than TRUE.

Third, a `mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)` returns an array, you have to use array notation to get the only returned value i.e. `$row[0]`

Also when any `mysqli_` function fails it leaves some error information that is very useful, so show that info or send it to an application error file if you dont want users to see them when the code goes live.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(ID) from bruker");

if ($sql === FALSE) {
    echo "Funker ikke";
    echo mysqli_error($db);
    exit;
} else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM);
    echo $row[0];
}
```